# Magento 2: Can create two different templates for the Homepage?

Tags: magento2, template, home-page

Am I able to create two different templates for the homepage and change between them whenever I want?
I'm trying to create a new homepage, but I don't want to lose the old one, so I disable it and then I tried to create a new page with the
`Title: Home Page` and in 
`URL Key: home` 
but when I try to Save the Page the next message is showed:
`Could not save the page: Unique constraint violation found`
There is any way to create a new "home page" template, without lose the old one?

Comment: You `cannot use same url-key in same scope`. If the scope is `different then you can use the same`. Like if `you have 2 diff store then you can use url-key "home" for both stores. But not in the same store or same website` or if you `have an url-key "home" which is set to ALL STORES then also you cant use it again`.

Comment: @KingshukDeb I tried as well to change the url-key in the old homepage template, but I was not able to do it. But is more clearly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If having more than one store view, we can create two cms pages for each store view with the same url key.
However, we don't need to create the new cms home page with the same url. We can create a new cms page. And then, change the home page via config: **STORES > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that help! I thought that only disable the page would be enough!